# My Ajax javascript code isn't working

Tags: javascript, ajax

My Ajax javascript code isn't working...
Here is the code:

```
function getMessages() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "process.php");
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I have my php script just doing a test saying: this is a test.
I can't figure out what I did wrong. Chrome javascript debugger says that I have an unxpected token "."

PHP Code:

```
    <?php if (!$_COOKIE["name"]) {
    echo "<form method='get' action = 'process.php'><input type = 'text' name = 'name'><input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit'></form>";
        } else {
     echo ' 
function getMessages(){var xmlhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest (); }
else { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200)   {     document.getElementById("box").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; } }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","process.php") ;
        xmlhttp.send(); }
        var is={ie:navigator.appName=="Microsoft InternetExplorer",java:navigator.javaEnabled(),ns:navigator.appName=="Netscape",ua:navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),version:parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.substr(21))||parseFloat(navigator.appVersion),win:navigator.platform=="Win32"
}
   is.mac=is.ua.indexOf("mac")>=0;
if(is.ua.indexOf("opera")>=0){is.ie=is.ns=false;is.opera=true;}
        if(is.ua.indexOf("agecko")>=0)
        {is.ie=is.ns=false;is.gecko=true;
}';
    echo "<textarea id=box rows=20 cols=20></textarea>
<form method='get' action = 'process.php'> 
<input type = 'text' name = 'message'>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit'>
 </form>";
    } ?>
```

Comment: May not solve your problem, but shouldn't "xmlhttp.readyStat" be "xmlhttp.readyState" (the e at the end is missing)?

Comment: You should add the PHP code you're using.

Comment: thanks, but that didn't solve the error

Comment: Edit: Removed some extra stuff I had added in. Should be the same as your code, just better formatted. Try this instead of your current PHP code: http://pastie.org/2815434

Answer (score 2):

`xmlhttp.readyStat` should be `xmlhttp.readyState` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

`readyStat` should be `readyState` for one. [Rest seems okay](http://jsfiddle.net/aditya/NgVXy/).

Comment: Do you have a page where you have this implemented that we can check? Context helps sometimes. The function itself is fine as the jsFiddle shows.

Comment: Safari console gives me this error: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getMessages" (Supposed to be on line 11) // Edit: After logging in, I also get this error "SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found 'xmlhttp' instead
" (Line 28)

Comment: Okay, logged in. I noticed that your `<script>` isn't closed, so that entire line (including the `<form>` and everything inside) is being taken as Javascript.

Comment: by the way, i am a javascript beginner.

Comment: I have a strange feeling the whitespaces and new-lines are what's screwing things up.

Comment: well, I made the javascript all one line because I'm using php to put it up.

Comment: No, the PHP isn't the problem. Use a [minifier](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) to get a single line.

Comment: @user1031149: I think looking at the PHP code that's writing out the Javascript is the only thing left to do.

Answer (score 1):

xmlhttp.send() to xmlhttp.send(null) can prevent IE bugs too